# "Finalmente" versus "infine"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, difference, adverbs

Quando devo usare "finalmente" e quando "infine"? Per fare un esempio, immaginate che sto descrivendo tre fotografie e scrivo alcune frasi che cominciano così:

> Nella prima fotografia, ...
>
> La seconda immagine mostra ...

Cosa posso scrivere dopo?

> - *Finalmente*, nella terza fotografia ...?
> - *Infine*, nella terza fotografia ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Finalmente" in questo caso io non lo userei. In italiano ha un significato simile a "¡por fin!", in quanto esprime sollievo o soddisfazione per la conclusione di qualcosa: "finalmente sei arrivato, sono venti minuti che ti aspetto", "finalmente (dopo tanti tentativi/dopo tanto tempo) sono riuscito a prendere la patente" etc.

Nel tuo esempio: "infine". Puoi anche dire, ovviamente:

- (Nel)la terza e ultima fotografia ...
- (Nel)l'ultima fotografia ...

Comment: Si può usare *finalmente* se vuoi trasmettere comprensione per il fatto che la lista era molto lunga o tediosa. 

E in testi storici penso che si trovi finalmente anche con stesso significato di infine. 

Se fossi straniero eviterei, visto il rischio di dire qualcosa che suona strano e visto che dicendo *infine* vai sul sicuro.